# Where can I ask about mainframe emulation? (Hercules and/or GCOS8)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am interested in the [Hercules emulator](http://www.hercules-390.org/) (System/370 and the likes), as well as potential emulators for the [GCOS-systems from Bull Group](http://www.bull.com/gcos-servers), preferably GCOS8 (if such emulators at all exist outside the enterprise sphere).

I have searched Super User, Server Fault and the general SE-wide search for GCOS, and there does not seem to be any specific questions about this operating system or its parent architecture... so I am unsure what site would be correct (if any).

Is there an appropriate SE-site for this/these topics?

Comment: Not enough information here to give you a good answer. What kinds of questions? Can you give examples of the kinds of questions you want to ask?

Comment: I don't know either of the systems being emulated, so my questions will likely be in the area of configuring and running the emulators. Questions like "what does X mean in this config", "what is required to make Y component work within this setup" and "where do I go to enable/modify Z functionality" - either about the emulator itself or the system being emulated, if the two are not so interconnected that for a Q&A purpose they can practically be regarded one and the same, as I have understood is the case for Hercules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best option is the site [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com). From their [Tour](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tour):

> [a] site for vintage-computer hobbyists interested in restoring, preserving, and using the classic computer and gaming systems of yesteryear.

A quick search for [Hercules S/370](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=hercules+s%2F370) and [GCOS](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=gcos) reveals some answers so I expect you'll find users that have knowledge there.

As always check their [help](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help) and ask on their [meta](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/) when in doubt about a specific question you want to ask.